# jasmine-jquery isn't finding an element in my fixture file

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm trying to do UI testing with jasmine-jquery. I'm using karma as my test runner and jasmine as my testing framework. I think I've loaded the fixture successfully and jasmine-jquery is listed as a testing framework inside my karma configuration.

However I'm unable to find an element in the DOM using jasmine-jquery. Why?

Directory structure

```
base
 spec
  javascripts
   fixtures
    myfixture.html
karma.conf.js
tests
 settingUpHTMLFixtures.test.js
```

myfixture.html

```
<div id="my-fixture">foo bar</div>
```

settingUpHTMLFixtures.test.js

```
jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath = 'base/spec/javascripts/fixtures';
loadFixtures('myfixture.html');
describe('testing out jasmine-jquery', function(){
  it('can find an element in the dom using jasmine-jquery', function(){
    expect($j('#my-fixture')).toBeInDOM();
  })
})
```

karma.conf.js

```
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: "",
    files: ["tests/**/*.test.js", 'spec/javascripts/fixtures/*.html'],
    frameworks: ['jasmine-jquery', 'jasmine', 'jasmine-matchers'],
    preprocessors: {
      "tests/**/*.test.js": ["webpack"]
    },
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    plugins : [
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-jasmine-jquery',
      'karma-jasmine-matchers',
      'karma-webpack',
      'karma-jasmine-html-reporter'
      ],
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    reporters: ['kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    browsers: ["Chrome"],
    //...
  });
};
```

At the moment I'm just getting the message that the test failed, which is
`testing out jasmine-jquery can find an element in the dom using jasmine-jquery FAILED
        Expected jQuery({ context: HTMLNode, selector: '#my-fixture' }) to be in d o m.
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (tests/settingUpHTMLFixtures.test.js:78:31)"`

Answer (score 1):

I had a path error. It was a mistake to create the base directory on my own. Karma simply serves everything from the base directory.

The only time I needed to use the word base was when setting the fixtures path (as shown in my settingUpHTMLFixtures.test.js code above)